# Elastic Search : cannot write a field name expecting a value

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch

Okay what I am trying to achieve here is parsing a json string and separating its fields and assigning them to variables. Next I am creating a builder to send data to the elastic for indexing. But I am getting this error which is really bugging me. I am unable to move forward.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {

        try {
            obj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
            System.out.println(obj.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            type = obj.getString("type");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Values for select");
        try {
            JSONArray jContent = (JSONArray) obj.get("values");

        for (int iterate = 0; iterate < jContent.length(); iterate++) {
            JSONObject inner = jContent.getJSONObject(iterate);
            String inner_label = (String) inner.get("label");
            String val = (String) inner.get("value");
            boolean sel;
            try {
                sel = (boolean) inner.get("selected");

            } catch (JSONException j) {
                sel = false;
            }

            builder.startObject("Extras").field("inner_lab", inner_label).field("inner_value", val).field("Selected", sel).endObject();

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {

    }

    try {
        label = obj.getString("label");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        access = obj.getBoolean("access");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        access = false;
    }

    try {
        role = obj.getString("role");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        role = null;
    }

    try {
        subtype = obj.getString("subtype");
    } catch (JSONException e) {

        subtype = null;
    }

    try {
        maxlength = obj.getString("maxlength");
    } catch (JSONException e) {

        maxlength = null;
    }

    try {
        name = obj.getString("name");
    } catch (JSONException e) {

        name = null;
    }

    try {
        description = obj.getString("description");
    } catch (JSONException e) {

        description = null;
    }

    try {
        classname = obj.getString("className");
    } catch (JSONException e) {

        classname = null;
    }

    try {
        placeholder = obj.getString("placeholder");
    } catch (JSONException e) {

        placeholder = null;
    }

    try {
        value = obj.getString("value");
    } catch (JSONException e) {

        value = null;
    }

    try {
        required = obj.getBoolean("required");
    } catch (JSONException e) {

        required = false;
    }
    try {
        toggle = obj.getBoolean("toggle");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        toggle = false;
    }
    try {
        inline = obj.getBoolean("inline");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        inline = false;
    }
    try {
        enableother = obj.getBoolean("other");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        enableother = false;
    }
    try {
        multipleFiles = obj.getBoolean("multiple");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        multipleFiles = false;
    }
    try {
        style = obj.getString("style");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        style = null;
    }
    try {
        min = obj.getString("min");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        min = null;
    }
    try {
        max = obj.getString("max");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        max = null;
    }
    try {
        step = obj.getString("step");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        step = null;
    }
    try {
        rows = obj.getString("rows");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        rows = null;
    }

    // //Indexing Data..
    (HERE) builder.startObject("values").field("access", access).field("role", role).field("subtype", subtype)
            .field("maxlength", maxlength).field("name", name).field("description", description)
            .field("className", classname).field("label", label).field("placeholder", placeholder)
            .field("value", value).field("required", required).field("style", style).field("toggle", toggle)
            .field("inline", inline).field("other", enableother).field("multiple", multipleFiles)
            .field("content", content).field("min", min).field("max", max).field("step", step)
            .field("rows", rows).endObject();
    builder.endObject();
    resp = client.prepareIndex("clien", userName).setSource(builder).execute().actionGet();

}
```

}

At (HERE) position erro keeps showing up..Cannot write a field name expecting a value. 
Also is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to do here. thanks for the help.

Comment: Try use the Java API for ES search responses, see SearchResponse 
class. You do not need to parse HTTP REST JSON by yourself.

Comment: @user7790438 I am using IndexResponse to create index, and I am tried sending json object but it accepted. After searching i got to know that index response setSource don't accept json object only map. And I think SearchResponse is for querying right..here I am indexing.